# How to use emacs CLI on a Linux server remotely from Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, emacs, putty

I have emacs-nox installed on a CentOS 6.5 server.  I had been using PuTTY from Windows to remote into this server.  However, I discovered that in emacs, I cannot hit Ctrl+A (somewhat like other combinations found [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/PuTTY)) because it is gobbled by PuTTY and doesn't make it to emacs.

My question is, is there a way to get PuTTY to work better?  If not, what ssh client for Windows would allow me to remotely use emacs in CLI mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows I have found [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to work great.  Just do not download everything when you install packages as that will take up way too much memory.

When using the installer run a search for "openssh" and you should be good to go.

Also, if you go this route, 'ncurses' is also a must have.

I tested emacs using cygwin's ssh and ctrl+a worked fine.

Comment: What happens without ncurses?

Comment: When using the cygwin terminal in windows, ncurses emulates a lot of common unix-like commands like "clear" for instance.  It is not necessary to have, and does not affect anything while you are using ssh to connect to another machine.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249070/how-do-i-get-the-clear-command-in-cygwin